# VBA macro for creating new worksheets and name by date in a cell and then copying all rows with that date and pasting into the right sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So here is the scenario, a workbook is created and information is pulled from our production software. The IT department says they have coded this extraction as best they could. It is in a table format and I have the first half of my macro written where it sorts through some column, and based on that information changes other columns. I also had to insert a column and copy the date information over as text so that it can be used as a new sheet's name. I have tried a bunch of code I have found online but I can't adapt it correctly. Here is where I'm stuck:

I now need it to look at my date [Shipping2] column, and row by row (some sort of loop) check if the cell's date is older than or equal to tomorrow's date (the report is pulled daily so I need it to be based on a changing Now() date). If it is <=tomorrow, then that whole row needs to be copied and pasted on one new sheet with tomorrow's date. Luckily it is sorted in ascending order already.

From there it will then add a new sheet for each new date encounters, and copy all the rows that have that date and paste it into that sheet.

[image]

I'll show you what my macro looks like so far but I am open to any suggestions on this so I will leave off all my failed attempts at this. Thank you in advance.

```
`Sub Arrange()
'
' Arrange Schedule Macro
'

' insert new column next to [sqft]

    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

' copy paste [sqft] to [column1]

        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Sqft]").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range( _
        "Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[[Sqft]:[Column1]]"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault

' display only status 340/342/345/360

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("340", "342", "345", "360"), Operator _
        :=xlFilterValues

' [column1] to 0

    Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Column1]").Value = 0

'Display all status

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5

' Display Break Shapes

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="Brake Shapes - 25"

' [column1] to 0

    Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Column1]").Value = 0

' Display IG and IG-Lami

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=IG Laminated - 52", Operator:=xlOr, _
        Criteria2:="=Insulating - 50"

' Specail Sqfts to 0

        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Colored Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Shaped Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Polishing Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Holes Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Notches Sqft]").Value = 0

' Display Ig and Ig-lami status 345 and 360

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="=345", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:= _
        "=360"

' [Batch] to *

    Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Batch]").Value = "*"

'Display all status

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5

' Display Lami/Mulitlami

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="=Laminated - 55", Operator:=xlOr, _
        Criteria2:="=Multilaminated - 56"

' Display Lami/Mulitlami status 342 and 360

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="=342", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:= _
        "=360"

' [Batch] to *

    Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Batch]").Value = "*"

'Display all status

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5

' Display [Business Type] not IG/Ig-lami nor lami/multilami

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("Brake Shapes - 25", _
        "Controluz IGBU - 60", "Creanza Color - 81", "Creanza Span - 80", _
        "Custom Glass Doors - 10", "Fabricated Products - 30", "Flat Glass - 35", _
        "Frameless Heavy Glass - 12", "Royal Door - 20", "Tempered Glass - 45"), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

' Display status 340 and 360

     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="=340", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:= _
        "=360"

' [Batch] to *

    Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Batch]").Value = "*"

'Display all status

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=5

'Display all business

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=4

'display * [batch]

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="~*"

' Qty and Specail Sqfts to 0

        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Qty]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Colored Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Shaped Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Polishing Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Holes Sqft]").Value = 0
        Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Notches Sqft]").Value = 0

'display all [batch]

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=1

'
' autosum2 Macro
'

' [column1]

   Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Column1]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Column1]" & LastRow & ")"

' [Qty]

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Qty]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Qty]" & LastRow & ")"

' [OrigQty]

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[OrigQty]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[OrigQty]" & LastRow & ")"

' [Sqft]

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

' [DollarAmt]

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[DollarAmt]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[DollarAmt]" & LastRow & ")"

' blank cells will put autosum in wrong cell
' [Colored Sqft] field=15

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=15, Criteria1:="="

   Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Colored Sqft]").Value = 0

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=15

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Colored Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Colored Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

' [Shaped Sqft] field=16

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:="="

   Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Shaped Sqft]").Value = 0

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=16

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Shaped Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Shaped Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

' [Polishing Sqft] field=17

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:="="

   Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Polishing Sqft]").Value = 0

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=17

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Polishing Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Polishing Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

' [Holes Sqft] field=18

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:="="

   Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Holes Sqft]").Value = 0

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=18

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Holes Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Holes Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

' [Notches Sqft] field=19

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=19, Criteria1:="="

   Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Notches Sqft]").Value = 0

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=19

  Range("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Notches Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
  Formula = "=Sum(Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500[Notches Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

'
'
'new shipping2 column

   Sheets("FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300-50").Select
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("G1").Value = "Shipping2"
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.Formula = "=Text(F2,""mm-dd-yy"")"




'
'
'
'
' format dollaramt as currency

    ActiveSheet.Columns("M").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("I:L").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("P:T").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:W").AutoFit
    Worksheets("FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300-50").Columns("F").Hidden = True

'
'
'
'
'
'

' needtoship Macro

    'Add and Name Sheet

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Need to Ship"

    'Display * [Batch}

    Sheets("FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300-50").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="~*"

    ' define variable

       lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row

    ' select displayed talbe

    Range("A1:W" & lr).Select

    ' copy

    Selection.Copy

    'paste to Need to Ship sheet

    Sheets("Need to Ship").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'restore main sheet

    Sheets("FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300-50").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500").Range. _
        AutoFilter field:=1

      'select new sheet

    Sheets("Need to Ship").Select



' Format table

 ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"
    Range("Table2[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"

'autosum table 2
        ' [column1]

           Range("Table2[Column1]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Column1]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [Qty]

          Range("Table2[Qty]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Qty]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [OrigQty]

          Range("Table2[OrigQty]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[OrigQty]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [Sqft]

          Range("Table2[Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [DollarAmt]

          Range("Table2[DollarAmt]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[DollarAmt]" & LastRow & ")"


        ' [Colored Sqft]

          Range("Table2[Colored Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Colored Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [Shaped Sqft]

          Range("Table2[Shaped Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Shaped Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [Polishing Sqft]

          Range("Table2[Polishing Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Polishing Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [Holes Sqft]

          Range("Table2[Holes Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Holes Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

        ' [Notches Sqft]

          Range("Table2[Notches Sqft]").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0). _
          Formula = "=Sum(Table2[Notches Sqft]" & LastRow & ")"

' format new sheet

    Worksheets("Need to Ship").Columns("A:W").AutoFit












End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Operating under the assumption that every time it is tabula rasa (no sheets created:

```
Sub CopyToAnotherSheet()

Dim currentTable As ListObject
Dim shippingIndex As Integer
Dim sheetReference As Object
Dim setDate As String
Dim cell As Range

Set sheetReference = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set currentTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300 50").ListObjects("Table_FlatGlassSchedulingStatus300_500")

shippingIndex = currentTable.ListColumns("Shipping2").Index

For Each cell In currentTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(shippingIndex).Cells
    setDate = IsTommorowOrEarlier(cell.Value)
    If IsEmpty(sheetReference(setDate)) Then

        Set sheetReference(setDate) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        sheetReference(setDate).Name = setDate
        currentTable.HeaderRowRange.Copy
        sheetReference(setDate).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
    sheetReference(setDate).Rows(PasteRow(sheetReference(setDate))).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next cell
Set sheetReference = Nothing
End Sub

Function IsTommorowOrEarlier(getDate As Date) As String


If getDate <= DateAdd("d", 1, Date) Then

    IsTommorowOrEarlier = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")

Else

    IsTommorowOrEarlier = Format(getDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")

End If

End Function

Function PasteRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long

If ws.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then

    PasteRow = 1

Else

    With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

        PasteRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row + 1

    End With

End If

End Function
```

**Edit:**
changed set date to string also redifned the function:

```
Function IsTommorowOrEarlier(getDate As Date) As String


If getDate <= DateAdd("d", 1, Date) Then

    IsTommorowOrEarlier = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Date), "mm-dd-yyyy")

Else

    IsTommorowOrEarlier = Format(getDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")

End If

End Function
```

It is a bit complex I use a dictionary to create a list of Date -> Worksheet reference and then paste, maybe someone will come up with a easier solution but this can work. For large tables it can also get a bit sluggish due to the fact that we are looping row by row.

Comment: Thank you for you help, it looks like it's going to work. The only issue I'm having is that it is giving me a error for the first sheet name. (01/31/2017) can't be used because of the (mm/dd/yyyy), I am trying to change the format to ("mm-dd-yy") but it doesn't change it for the line "sheetReference(setDate).Name = setDate" would you know how to get it to accept the format change? Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Hi I just checked on your screenshot that you are converting your date to a string in Shipping2 
Instead of using =Text() apply formatting to the cell. Its going to be hard to define "tommorow" then working with a String object. If you need to use the string let me know Ill add a method that converts the string back into a date.

Comment: I apologize it isn't, I have still been trying to get it to work but I can't. I went on and developed the sheet enough so my Scheduling Department can use it but I'm still trying to figure it out. 

Yes I had converted it to a string so that I could use the date as the Sheet Name. I'm not sure if I can turn it off but it won't let me create a sheet with (mm/dd/yyyy) because the back slashes aren't accepted. 

I have tried making a separate column so it can check the date in the date format, but then use the cell next to it (mm-dd-yyyy) as the sheet name. Any additional help would be great.

Comment: I Ammended the code so now it retuns a string as mm-dd-yyyy. Check it out.